# MVVM Light Messenger.Register not working

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

In my MainViewModel I have only RelayCommands that open different pages.
Theese commands are like this

```
 Messenger.Default.Send<int>(2015);
 ViewModel.ReportViewModel reportVM = new ReportViewModel(report);
 Views.ReportView pagReport = new ReportView() { DataContext = reportVM };
 ApplicationHelper.NavigationService(pagReport);
```

in ReportViewModel I have

```
 public ReportViewModel(string report)
 {
   Messenger.Default.Register<int>(this, Doit);
   ShowReport(report);
 }

 private void Doit(int val)
 {
   int test = val;//code never touch this line
 }
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Sanity check: Have you put a breakpoint on your Messenger.Default.Send? Is that line hit?

Comment: Yes of course. Even the Register is hit but it's not executed that procedure.

Comment: I notice that you're instantiating/newing up the reportVM *after* you send the message. If there isn't an instance of ReportViewModel *before* the message is sent then that message has no listener.

Comment: Thank you ! This was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Per my comment above, you're instantiating/newing up reportVM *after* you send the message. If there isn't an instance of ReportViewModel *before* the message is sent then that message has no listener.

```
//Instantiate first:
ViewModel.ReportViewModel reportVM = new ReportViewModel(report);
Views.ReportView pagReport = new ReportView() { DataContext = reportVM };
ApplicationHelper.NavigationService(pagReport);

//Send the message:
Messenger.Default.Send<int>(2015);
```